# Does software exists that will give you the possible schematics of an analog circuit?

Tags: schematics

Does software, and/or perhaps an actual device, exist that will give you the possible schematics of an analog circuit from measurements of the circuit?

Comment: Sure. There are programs to calculate filters. Is that what you need?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, or at least not that usable. Because a lot of the schematics handles safety or bad weather conditions (like switching polarity accidentally, current spike protection, overheating protection etc). You don't want to or cannot find this by measuring.

Comment: There may be some very limited analog HDL packages that can draw some schematics, or filter design programs, but in the general case no.  There are infinite permutations of some analog functions so it's not practical.  And what would you measure anyway?  The impulse or step response?  Frequency sweep? What about non-linear analog circuits?

Comment: There is more engineering than reverse engineering, and not enough reverse engineering to relegate the task to software. Find a consultant or a hacker.

Comment: What types of circuits do you want to "synthesize"? Will you provide "specs" or provide "impulse response"? Will you provide the SNR and the datarate?

Comment: A circuit is not dictated by a few measurements or even plenty of measurements. No, in a general case no.

Answer (score 2):

If you start from a specifcation rather than a measurement, what you're describing is called circuit *synthesis*.

Synthesis is very common in digital design, where we usually work by making a description of the hardware behavior in a *hardware description language* and then using a synthesis tool to produce a digital logic circuit to implement that behavior.

In analog design, it's also possible to at least design subcircuits or circuit blocks using synthesis.

For example, [Genesys](https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=1824323&nid=-34275.870670.00&id=1824323&cmpid=zzfindeesof-genesys-synthesis) is a software package from Keysight that can synthesize filters for RF frequencies.

For lower frequencies, some chip vendors provide web tools to generate circuits using their chips to provide certain functions. TI's [WeBench](http://www.ti.com/tools-software/design-center/webench-power-designer.html) is probably the most prominent of these, used to produce switching power supply designs or [op-amp active filters](http://www.ti.com/design-tools/signal-chain-design/webench-filters.html).